The text box of the duplicate search dialog in Staging Ground is unreachable on mobile
On my iPhone 12 Mini running Firefox, I am unable to vote to close as duplicate.
On the initial Staging Ground review screen, when I click open an SG question, "Vote to close as duplicate" is offered as an option I can pick; the screen is a bit crammed, but it works.

(It seems rather excessive that the action dialog takes up more than a third of the available area on the screen, though. If the stupid menu bar could be scrolled out of view, that would slightly mitigate this awkwardness.)
But then when I click Submit, the dialog where I could search for a suitable duplicate won't let me search:

In case you are unfamiliar with this dialog, it has a text box where I should be able to enter search terms, above the "Similar questions" text, but it's outside the visible viewport. I can briefly pull down the screen and expose it, but there is no way to enter text there. When I release the dragged-down screen, it jumps right back to where it was.
(Again, it's kind of silly that the design apparently takes care to leave space for buttons I cannot interact with, instead of use the available space for the currently active modal dialog.)
For the tags where I am a gold badge holder, a crude workaround is to randomly accept one of the visible duplicates, then go back and replace them on the closed question, though that is almost impossible as well. (Previous bug report: The "edit duplicates" dialog is broken on narrow screens in the current responsive design)
(The question in the screen shot is an innocent bystander; I just picked a recent Staging Ground post to get screenshots from.)

BTW, there are userscripts & bookmarklets to un-stick the top bar. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368984/334566

@PM2Ring Thanks, but unfortunately I couldn't get the linked bookmarklet to work on IOS Firefox.

Oh. It looks like bookmarklets have been disabled on IOS Firefox. https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/issues/5626 Sorry about giving you false hopes. :(
